# Auto expand +- row headers for new rows in Power BI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way of auto clicking/expanding this row header + icon, so that when new rows are added to the dataset they are automatically expanded in the visual?

What's weird about this is that I have 1 existing report where this behaviour automatically happens for.

And I have another report where it doesn't.

I don't think I changed anything for the report where it automatically happens, but something is obviously different!

[image]